# How do I iterate through a list of objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a list(phonebook) of objects(record) but I'm new to python and it is not recognizing that record is a objects in the list. How would I call objects in this instance?

Ive tried looking at tutorials of python for loops but none reference how to call an object in a list.

```
class record:
    def __init__(self,telephone,lastname,firstname):
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname

class PhoneBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.phonebook = []

    def printphonebook(self):
        for record in self.phonebook:
            x = 0
            print(self.phonebook[x])
            x = x + 1
```

Expected output would be the list of objects including the telephone number, last name, and first name.

Comment: *All* tutorials show how to iterate a loop. It makes no difference what the content of the list is. Your `x` is pointless, you should just be printing `record`.

Comment: Ive made the adjustments you recommended and it is still not working. regardless wouldn't record still not print in plain text?

Comment: you're might be mixing up some concepts here. First, you've made a class, but atleast in the sections here, 1: youve never made the objects and 2: you've never put anything in the phonebook list. Second, the name record in the for loop has absolutely no relation with the name record of the class.

Comment: As I stated record is not being identified in the IDE as the object instance as well. So I believe the problem could lie deeper.(in response to Daniel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to print an instance of a class. So you should provide the special `__str__` method to tell python how the object should be printed. `__str__()` must return a string: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) the docs.

```
class record:
    def __init__(self,telephone,lastname,firstname):
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname

    def __str__(self):
        #returning a string with the content, you can edit the string to fit your needs.
        #here I am using formatted string literals, works with python >= 3.6
        return f"Last name: {self.lastname}, First Name: {self.firstname}, Telephone: {self.telephone}"

class PhoneBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.phonebook = []

    def printphonebook(self):
        for entry in self.phonebook:
            print(entry)
```

What happens here is that when you call `print(record)` the `__str__()` method is used to provide a string representing the content of the instance.

So if you do:

```
book = PhoneBook()
book.phonebook.append(record(800, "Wayne", "Bruce"))
book.phonebook.append(record(1234,  "Kent", "Clark"))
book.phonebook.append(record(499, "Prince", "Diana"))

book.printphonebook()
```

This will print:

> Last name: Wayne, First Name: Bruce, Telephone: 800
>   Last name: Kent, First Name: Clark, Telephone: 1234
>   Last name: Prince, First Name: Diana, Telephone: 499

Comment: Thank you very much, However it is still not giving me any output and the record reference in the for loop isn't showing it as a class in my IDE. Thanks for the __str__ tip though I didnt know about that.

Comment: I've just edited my answer. I realized that you were using the same name `record` for the class name and the looping variable. That is never a good idea. In my case it was printing however. I am not using an IDE. Try to run your code from the command line and see if it prints

Answer (score 0):

1. You have no elements in your `self.phonebook`. Of course it prints nothing.
2. Every iteration you create `x=0` so you always will print the first item:

```
class record:
    def __init__(self,telephone,lastname,firstname):
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname

class PhoneBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.phonebook = [1,2,3,4,5]

    def printphonebook(self):
        for record in self.phonebook:
            x = 0
            print(self.phonebook[x])
            x = x + 1

a = PhoneBook()
a.printphonebook()
```

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

3. Your `x` index is really pointless, you can just print `record`:

```
class record:
    def __init__(self,telephone,lastname,firstname):
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname

class PhoneBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.phonebook = [1,2,3,4,5]

    def printphonebook(self):
        for record in self.phonebook:
            print(record)

a = PhoneBook()
a.printphonebook()
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

So: 1. Fill your `self.phonebook` with ANY elements 2. Print `record`, without indices.

Comment: Ah yes stupid mistake with the x variable. The instances of record are being added in main sorry forgot to include that code. So furthermore how would I handle this if I'm printing records stored in phonebook?